# Why is postman sending the same request auth header with every request

Tags: spring, postman

I am working on spring rest project, and in the rest controller I'm taking the basic auth user id as String `userID=request.getUserPrincipal().getName();`

When I get the request from postman, I always get the same userName every time. I checked with different users and without users also.

Answer (score 0):

In postman request header auth cookies are not refreshing after first successful request. We can try in SOAPUI tool in that every request auth header is different for every request and validating every time separately. We can check debugging with installing postman interceptor also. If we check the cookies associated with the request we can easily observe auth related cookies are not changing.